# Windows 10 in VirtualBox keeps changing resolution

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10, virtual-machine, resolution

I'm running Windows 10 in a VirtualBox on a Windows 10 host. I installed the guest drivers provided by Oracle and indeed Windows dynamically changes the resolution of the screen to match the size of the VirtualBox window, but every now and then it goes back to a small resolution leaving most of the window unused.

Any ideas what's going on? or how to fix it?

**Update:** I managed to catch a notification, apparently, the video driver is crashing and that's why it's reverting back.

Comment: Update the display driver to one that supports Windows 10 be sure your using a version of VBox that supports Windows 10

Comment: I'm using the latest Virtual Box and I installed the drivers from it, so it's using the latest Virtual Box video driver too in the guest OS.

Comment: Has this issue been reported by anyone to Oracle/VirtualBox?  If it has not been reported by somebody else, have you reported the issue, its possible its simply a bug.  VirtualBox struggled to even support Windows 10.

Comment: I have no idea if someone else reported. I didn't, I don't know how to gather crash data and report it to VirtualBox.

Comment: VirtualBox has a public bug tracker.  I would see if you can locate a recent bug report that matches your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the Windows 10 Power & Sleep setting of your Screen to Never turn off.

[VirtualBox ticket #14409](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14409) discusses this issue with Windows 10, and proposes this workaround. It also provides other context that may be helpful.